# Evaluating $\oint_c x\,dx-y\,dy$ (and others) over unit circle $c$. I'm not sure I understand how those separate derivatives are supposed to work.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

The question says:

> Solve the following line integrals, where $c$ is the circle with radius $1$ centered at the origin, that can be parametrized by $ c : [0,2\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 : t \mapsto c(t) = (\cos(t),\sin(t))$.
>
> (i) $\;\oint_c x\,dx-y\,dy$
>
> (ii) $\;\oint_c x\,dx+x\,dy$
>
> (iii) $\;\oint_c y\,dx$
>
> (iv) $\;\oint_c dy$

I think I'm supposed to use Green's theorem and solve these integrals as a double integral on the region of a circle, and then use polar coordinate substitution? But I'm not sure I understand how those separate derivatives are supposed to work like in "$x\,\mathrm{d}x-y\,\mathrm{d}y$" for example.

Comment: Is your question how to use Green's theorem to compute these integrals, or is it what precisely notation like $x\,\mathrm{d}x - y\,\mathrm{d}y$ means?

Comment: @J_P I'm really asking what notation like $xdx-ydy$ means, but I could use some help in how to use green's theorem to compute those integrals, although I think I might be able to do it myself once I understand how this notation works

Answer (score 1):

I think the best explanation for this $\mathrm{d}x$ notation is in terms of differential forms, but that may be too advanced, so let's use simpler notions.

Suppose $\gamma:[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is a continuously differentiable curve and suppose further that $f:U\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a differentiable function defined on some open neighborhood of the image of $\gamma$ (so, in the case of the circle, it would be defined at least on some thick annular region around the circle). Then if $g$ is any continuous function defined on the image of $\gamma$, we set
$$
\int_\gamma g\,\mathrm{d}f = \int_a^b g(\gamma(t)) \nabla\!f(\gamma(t))\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}\gamma(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
What happens if we reparametrize $\gamma$? If $[c,d]$ is another interval and $\phi:[c,d]\longrightarrow [a,b]$ is continuously differentiable with $\phi(c)=a$, $\phi(d)=b$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\int_c^d \!\!g(\gamma(\phi(s))) \nabla\!f(\gamma(\phi(s)))&\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}\gamma(\phi(s))}{\mathrm{d}s}\mathrm{d}s=\!\!\int_c^d\!\!g(\gamma(\phi(s))) \nabla\!f(\gamma(\phi(s)))\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}\gamma}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg\vert_{t=\phi(s)}\!\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi(s)}{\mathrm{d}s}\mathrm{d}s=\\
&= \int_a^b g(\gamma(t)) \nabla\!f(\gamma(t))\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}\gamma(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}
by the change of variables formula, so the integral is unchanged.

Morally speaking,
$$
\mathrm{d}f=\nabla\!f(\gamma(t))\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}\gamma(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
The dot product of the gradient with the tangent vector of the curve tells us how much the function $f$ changes when we move infinitesimally along the curve. The integral then just sums all these infinitesimal changes. Now if we have several pairs of functions $g_1, f_1$, $g_2, f_2$, ..., we can just set
$$
\int_\gamma g_1\mathrm{d}f_1+g_2\mathrm{d}f_2+ ...=\int_\gamma g_1\mathrm{d}f_1 + \int_\gamma g_2\mathrm{d}f_2+...
$$
as a sum of integrals.

Let's examine your example with $x\,\mathrm{d}x-y\,\mathrm{d}y$: we have $x(c(t))=\cos(t)$, $y(c(t))=\sin(t)$, $\nabla x(c(t))=(1,0)$, $\nabla y(c(t))=(0,1)$, $\frac{\mathrm{d}c}{\mathrm{d}t}=(-\sin(t),\cos(t))$. Hence
$$
\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}x\,\mathrm{d}x-y\,\mathrm{d}y = \int_0^{2\pi} (-\cos(t)\sin(t)-\sin(t)\cos(t))\,\mathrm{d}t=-\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(2t)\,\mathrm{d}t=0
$$
As for Green's formula, if $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$ and $\gamma$ is injective, then your curve bounds a region $D$. The formula is then that for any continuously differentiable $g_1, g_2$ defined on a neighborhood of $D$:
$$
\int_\gamma g_1\mathrm{d}x + g_2\mathrm{d}y = \iint_D \bigg(\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}\bigg)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
Importantly, the curve must be oriented counterclockwise, otherwise there would be a factor of $-1$ in this equality. In the case we just looked at, $g_1=x$ and $g_2=y$, so the partial derivatives entering into the double integral are $0$ and the answer is again $0$, as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

> Since there is no indication to apply *[Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Theorem)*
> it rather seems we are expected to calculate the line integral by using the given closed path parametrisation of the unit circle
> \begin{align*}
> c:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 : t \mapsto c(t) = (\cos(t),\sin(t))
> \end{align*}
> as it is stated.
> So we want to calculate the four line integrals
> \begin{align*}
> \oint_c x\,dx-y\,dy&\qquad\qquad\oint_c x\,dx+x\,dy\tag{1.1,$\quad$1.2}\\
> \oint_c y\,dx&\qquad\qquad\oint_c dy\tag{1.3,$\quad$1.4}
> \end{align*}

Note, the line notation used here is just a space-saving notation for the vector-based notation which is often used when parametrisation comes into play. Since then we can conveniently write, given the parameter $t$ varies in the interval $[t_1 ,t_2]$ and $c=(x(t),y(t))$
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\oint_c a(x,y)\,dx+b(x,y)\,dy=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left(a(x(t),y(t))\dot{x}(t)+b(x(t),y(t))\dot{y}(t)\right)dt}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

In fact we have a shortcut for some of the four line-integrals in (1.1) to (1.4). We recall a *fundamental theorem of line integrals* which states that if we integrate within a *simply connected region* the integral
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\oint_c a(x,y)\,dx+b(x,y)\,dy=0}\qquad\mathrm{iff}\qquad
\color{blue}{\frac{\partial a(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial b(x,y)}{\partial x}}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

- **Example 1.1:** We have according to (2)
  \begin{align*}
  \oint_c a(x,y)\,dx+b(x,y)\,dy=\oint_c x\,dx-y\,dy
  \end{align*}
  It follows
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial a(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=0
  \qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad
  \frac{\partial b(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial (-y)}{\partial x}=0\\
  \end{align*}
  and we conclude according to (3)
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\oint_c x\,dx-y\,dy=0}
  \end{align*}
- **Example 1.2:** We have according to (2)
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\oint_cx\,dx+x\,dy}
  &=\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\cos (t)\left(-\sin(t)\right)+\cos^2(t)\right)\,dt\\
  &=-\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(t)\sin(t)\,dt+\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^2(t)\,dt\\
  &=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(2t)\,dt+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\cos(2t)+1\right)\,dt\\
  &=-\frac{1}{4}\cos(2t)\Big|_{0}^{2\pi}+\frac{1}{4}\sin(2t)\Big|_{0}^{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2}t\Big|_{0}^{2\pi}\\
  &\,\,\color{blue}{=\pi}
  \end{align*}
- **Example 1.3:** We have according to (2) and example 1.2
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\oint_c y\,dx}
  &=\int_0^{2\pi} \sin (t)\left(-\sin(t)\right)\,dt\\
  &=-\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(1-\cos^2(t)\right)\,dt\\
  &=-t\Big|_{0}^{2\pi}+\pi\\
  &\,\,\color{blue}{=-\pi}
  \end{align*}
- **Example 1.4:** We have according to (2)
  \begin{align*}
  \oint_c a(x,y)\,dx+b(x,y)\,dy=\oint_c dy
  \end{align*}
  It follows
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial a(x,y)}{\partial y}=0
  \qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad
  \frac{\partial b(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0\\
  \end{align*}
  and we conclude according to (3)
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\oint_c dy=0}
  \end{align*}